# Twitter API cursor not showing in .json (Python)

Tags: python, twitter, data-mining, twitterapi-python

I read about the cursor documentation in Twitter's API  [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/pagination)

I want to be able to see `next_cursor_str` from.json

I used the code from this twitter's gidhub [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Sampled-Stream/sampled-stream.py)

But when I used `url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?max_results=100&query={}&{}&cursor=-1".format(query, tweet_fields)`

The error:

```
Exception: (400, '{"errors":[{"parameters":{"cursor":["-1"]},"message":"The query parameter `[cursor] is not one of [query,start_time,end_time,since_id,until_id,max_results,next_token,expansions,tweet.fields,media.fields,poll.fields,place.fields,user.fields]"}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}')`
```

How can I fixed this so I can use cursoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursoring as documented on that page applies to version 1.1 of the Twitter API, and you are targeting v2. You've also linked to a streaming API sample code example, but you've specified a REST recent search endpoint, which does not support streaming.

You need to use the `next_token` from the response to [paginate](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/paginate) in v2.

So you get the first page of results using:

`https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=snow`

And then take the `next_token` from the response and use it in the next query, for example:

`https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=snow&next_token=b26v89c19zqg8o3fobd8v73egzbdt3qao235oql`

Comment: let us know if this helps, and mark this as answered if so.